How to re-cache global variable?
I'm trying to change a global state (an opensimplex random seed), which I use in a function called from an @njited function. But once compiled, Numba fixes the global value and I'm not able to change it. Like so:
from numba import njit

global_var = 3

@njit
def func():
    return global_var - 3

print(func()) # prints 0
global_var = 5
print(func()) # prints 0 again, undesired

Is there some way I can change a global state? I've tried with closures and storing the state in a numba.experimental.jitclass, but couldn't get it to work. Here's an example of that:
from numba import njit, int32
from numba.experimental import jitclass

spec = [
    ('var', int32),
]
@jitclass(spec)
class State:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
    def set(self, var):
        self.var = var

state = State(1)

@njit
def get_state():
    return state.var

get_state() # throws error

The class attempt gets me a Numba not implemented error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\rnd\py\landslip\try-jit.py", line 20, in <module>
    get_state()
  File "D:\prog\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "D:\prog\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.NumbaNotImplementedError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: native lowering)
<numba.core.base.OverloadSelector object at 0x00000206A85AC7D0>, (instance.jitclass.State#206a825e050<var:int32>,)
During: lowering "$4load_global.0 = global(state: <numba.experimental.jitclass.boxing.State object at 0x00000206A8597DC0>)" at D:\rnd\py\landslip\try-jit.py (18)


"Numba fixes the global value and I'm not able to change it" This is AFAIK expected, constants are considered immutable ones. Once the code is compiled, there is no way to change that. Changing the constant means recompiling the code for every possible value. An alternative solution is just to pass the constant in parameter of the function. Do you want this global variable to be a compile-time constant? (btw: note that mutating global variable is considered as a bad software engineering practice).

@JérômeRichard As stated, I'd like to change the seed value for the PRND sequence. The problem is that I have a call stack depth of 3-4 and several calls, so need to add the parameter on a dozen places. Would be nice to not have to repeat oneself that badly.

A global variable for a PRNG is a really bad idea. I strongly advise you not to do that. They did that for the libc and it was quite a disaster decades later. Numpy did the same and finally changed that (the API using a global-state is now a legacy one). One big issue is when you have multiple threads accessing the PRNG: this causes sneaky race conditions without lock and locks makes the PRNG very slow (due to cache line bouncing). There are other similar issues like this. Not to mention that it is not rare to need multiple PRNG for sake of reproducibility in large applications.

If you still want to do that, then there are no good fast solution. One way is to just switch to the objmode (for the PRNG) which is experimental and slow (interpreted) so certainly not a good idea. Actually, the main problem is that global variables generally lies in the CPython context and is an object so njit is not possible. The best solution is to escape Numba by calling a native function (eg. C) possibly via ctypes. this is not very efficient since the function will not be inlined but it might fit your needs. The other downside is that it is cumbersome to do.

Cython might be better in this case, but IDK if Cython support that. The escape solution can be fast though with cython since the target function can be compiled in the same translation unit (as the cythonized Python code). Also keep in mind that the access to global variable can be slower than local variables even in native language (dependent of the target platform).

Is it practical to wrap the function so the value is retrieved outside of it and passed as an argument?
from numba import njit

global_var = 3

@njit
def func_inner(local_var):
    return local_var - 3

def func():
    return func_inner(global_var)

print(func()) # prints 0
global_var = 5
print(func()) # prints 2

